# Sql query to fetch record between given range

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have written one stored procedure which give me set of records  for given range(for ex- if I give start Index 100 and page size is 50, it returns 50 records from given start index.). In my table records are more (around 14 lacks ), so it takes around 13 sec to execute the query. I want to optimize it.

here is my query-

```
SELECT  * FROM 
(           
  SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER( ORDER BY FE.CreatedDate DESC ) RowNumber,
      FE.FileEventId, MIN(FS.FolderSettingName) AS FolderSettingName,
      MIN(SD.StatusDescription) AS StatusDescription,
      MIN (@TotalRecords) as  RecordCount
  FROM FileEvent FE with (nolock)
  INNER JOIN  FolderSetting FS with (nolock) ON
                            FE.FolderSettingId = FS.FolderSettingId
  INNER JOIN  [Status] SD with (nolock) ON SD.StatusId = FE.StatusId
  WHERE FolderSettingName LIKE
                   ISNULL('%' + @FolderSettingName + '%' , FolderSettingName)
  AND FilePath LIKE ISNULL('%' + @FileName + '%' , FilePath)
  AND (@EventType IS NULL OR (ISNULL(FE.EventType, '') IN (SELECT * FROM
                       dbo.UFN_StringSplitByCommaSeparator(@EventType))))
  AND (@EventStatus IS NULL OR (ISNULL(SD.StatusDescription, '') IN
              (SELECT * FROM dbo.UFN_StringSplitByCommaSeparator(@EventStatus))))
  AND FE.ModifiedBy LIKE ISNULL('%' + @ProcessedBy + '%' , FE.ModifiedBy)
  AND FE.ModifiedDate BETWEEN @FileProcessedFromDate AND @FileProcessedToDate
  AND @LockByMachine IS NULL OR FE.LockedByMachine LIKE 
                               ISNULL('%' + @LockByMachine + '%' , 1)
  GROUP BY FileEventId, FE.CreatedDate
) FEvent
INNER JOIN  FileEvent with (nolock) ON FileEvent.FileEventId = FEvent.FileEventId
WHERE FEvent.RowNumber BETWEEN @StartIndex AND (@StartIndex + @PageSize)
```

Could you please tell me how to optimize it.

Comment: That's a lot of `LIKE` statements. If it fits, you could try using full text indexing instead. Also `ISNULL('%' + @FolderSettingName + '%')` will never match the first parameter as null.

Comment: joins are pretty expensive, you can change schema, do a view (if memory is not a concern) to make the query faster.

Comment: Are the tables properly indexed? Have you tried executing the query and showing the Execution Plans to see if any new indexes are suggested?

Comment: When there `like` statement and in the begining is `%` sql server don't use index... maybe you can delete from begining...